# no reconoce espacio en rewrite rule en htacces

Tags: php, variables, .htaccess, http-get, rewriterule

Hola tengo este código que utilizo para ocultar las extensiones de php y ahora quiero utilizar también para obtener variables por el método GET para obtener un código alfanumérico pero con una nueva pagina que no sea index.php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]+)$ codigoalfan.php?numero=$1
```

en esta ultima regla  [a-zA-Z0-9/_- ]le agrego el espacio y no responde.

a todas las paginas les quite el .php con la primera regla y en la segunda tengo que ocultar variables pero no funcina la segunda y si lo cambio de posicion todo se modifica dando error
¿como puedo utilizar ambas reglas para que reconozca el espacio entre palabras? por favor :)

lo que ya probe es utilizar al final [R=301,L] pero sigue sin funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Cuando dices:

> *"a todas las paginas les quite el .php con la primera regla"*

Es incorrecto, porque en `.htaccess` solo se analizan reglas y esa condición aplica cuando se solicita un archivo con extensión `.php` que no existe.

Por otra parte, no es conveniente tener espacios en URLs, porque los navegadores podrían escaparlos y remplazarlos con `+` o `%20`

Luego:

> en esta ultima regla `[a-zA-Z0-9/_- ]` le agrego el espacio y no responde.

Si te fijas, el guion medio `-` sirve para separar _"caracter de inicio" y "caracter final", evitando tener que escribir todo el alfabeto. Si tuvieras solo `[a-zA-Z0-9/_-]`, no habría problema, porque no hay un caracter posterior y no se busca una lista, pero, al agregar un espacio, estarías especificando que se busquen todos los caracteres entre guion bajo y espacio.

Pero, resulta que en las tablas de caracteres el espacio aparece antes que el guion bajo y esa expresión da error por orden inverso, el equivalente de `[z-a]`.

Puesto que el guion medio es un caracter especial, se debe escapar, quedando la expresión:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9/_\- ]
```

Cuando tengas dudas sobre lo que hace una expresión regular, visita https://regexr.com/

Comment: ok Gracias!, entonces mejor reemplazare los espacios : ) para evitarme mas complicaciones. Gracias !